# update ignite cache with time-stamp data

Tags: caching, cassandra, ignite

**My issue is that how to update cache with new entries from database table?**
my cache has my Cassandra table data suppose for till 3 p.m.
till that time user has purchase 3 item so my cache has 3 items entry associated with that user.

> But after sometime (say 30min) **what if user purchase 2 more item ?**

As i have 3 entry in cache it wont query from database, how to get those 2 new entry at time of calculation final bill.

**One option i have is to call `cache.loadCache(null, null)` every 15 min?** but some where this is not feasible to call every time?

Answer (score 1):

The better option here is to insert data not directly to Cassandra, but using Ignite. It will give a possibility to have always updated data in the cache without running any additional synchronizations with DB.

But if you will choose to run loadCache each time, you can add a timestamp to your object in DB and implement your own CacheStore, which will have addition method that will load only new data from DB. [Here](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-loading#section-ignitecacheloadcache) is a link to the documentation, it will help you to implement your own CacheStore.

Comment: setting `org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.Affinity` seems little bit help full but not the solution i'm looking for @Evgenii Zhuravlev ,as i wanna load only new data

Comment: and i though about insert record direct into ignite before but thing is like that we insert data from multiple places,like from android app,ios app,website,etc. So i'll have to change every thing or provide my team credential to do so (or give them rest access ).

Comment: I didn't mean that you should use Affinity aware cache store, I mean that you could load data by timestamp. I gave a link to the doc so you can found example how to create your own cachestore

Comment: Instead of adding partition to the object, you will add timestamp and you should load data not by partition, but filtering by timestamp

Comment: If the OP wishes to insert data using Ignite, it will lead to a write through strategy and would require use of synchronisation ( to ensure cache and cassandra are updated atomically ). IMO The transactions performed in Cassandra must be captured in a message bus or queue and a background job must update the cache from those transactions.